# Include Box2D in CLion

Tags: c++, box2d, clion

as the title said, I want to import Box2D in my project but I don't succeed. I downloaded Box2D 2.3.0 with the testbed, etc... it works fine on their project but when I want to import it in my project nothing work.

I even tried to copy testbed, box2D, glui and freeglut to my project and copy the main CMakeList but nothing is reconized...

Can someone please tell me how do I import Box2D in my project please.

Thanks a lot !

PS : I know this question is either obvious or you can find an answer on internet but I've tried for 2 days now and the result is nothing... And yeah I'm a total beginner with CLion so please be clear and kind ^^

Comment: Have you looked into how you might transform the Box2D `premake` file(s) into CMake configuration files? The latest Box2D doesn't support CMake like it used to but relies on `premake` instead. Googling 'premake for clion' I see clion doesn't directly support it yet but maybe you can get software like https://github.com/TurkeyMan/premake-cmake working for you to convert from premake to cmake.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the Box2D project to your project's root folder. Then make sure in `CMakeLists` you have `include_directories(.)` somewhere in there.